# Using MIN function with group by in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

My table `Trace` has the following columns:

- Trace_ID: primary Key, int
- Order_ID: foreign key Order(Order_id), int
- Status_ID: foreign key Status(Status_id), int
- Trace_Date: date
- Trace_Hour: time
- Trace_CreationDate: datetime2 (=getdate())

I need to retreive for each order the minimum (the smallest) `Trace_Date` and its corresponding `Trace_Hour` with a status of 'Closed' (table `Status`).

The difficulty for me is how to retrieve the correct `Trace_Hour`, because we can have more than one occurrence for the same date for the same order.

An example with only one `Order_ID` can help to understand better the situation:

```
Trace_ID  Order_ID  Status_ID  Trace_Date   Trace_Hour        Trace_CreationDate
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
176       502       1          2016-06-22   23:30:00.0000000    2016-07-08 09:18:39.0570000
177       502       6          2016-06-23   10:00:00.0000000    2016-07-08 09:18:39.0570000
178       502       37         2016-06-22   22:30:00.0000000    2016-07-08 09:18:39.0570000
```

The `status_ID = 1` has the status 'Closed'. So for the `Order_id = 502`, I want to retrieve `2016-06-22` as `Trace_Date` and `23:30:00` for `Trace_Hour`.

I tried to use this query:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        Order_ID, MIN(Trace_Date) AS Trace_Date
    FROM   
        Trace t WITH (nolock)
    INNER JOIN 
        [Status] s WITH (nolock) ON t.Status_ID = s.Status_ID
    WHERE  
        s.Closed = 1
    GROUP BY 
        Order_ID
)
SELECT
    MIN(t.Trace_Date) AS Trace_Date,
    MIN(Trace_Hour) AS Trace_Hour,
    t.Order_ID
FROM
    Trace t WITH (nolock)
INNER JOIN 
    cte WITH (nolock) ON t.Order_ID = cte.Order_ID 
                      AND t.Trace_Date = cte.Trace_Date
GROUP BY 
    t.Order_ID
```

This query doesn't return the correct result, because it retrieves `2016-06-22` as `Trace_Date` (Ok) and `22:30:00` as `Trace_Hour` which is not correct.

I don't have any deterministic column that I can use with the group by clause that allow me to retrieve the correct hour.

Does anyone have an idea how we can do this task?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You second select should be selecting from `cte`, not from `Trace`, otherwise what is the point of `cte`?

Comment: I use the table trace in the second select to get the column 'Trace_Hour' that is not selected in the cte

Comment: Yes sorry I saw that after I made the comment - tried to delete but S/O failed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By combining the `TraceHour` and `TraceDate` fields in a CTE, you can just `MIN()` that field and split off date and time later, when those fields are needed separately again:

```
with cte as (
    SELECT Order_ID
    , min(CAST(TraceDate as DATETIME) + CAST(TraceHour as TIME)) as Trace_DateTime
    FROM   Trace t with (nolock)
    INNER JOIN [Status] s with (nolock) ON t.Status_ID = s.Status_ID
    WHERE  s.Closed = 1
GROUP BY Order_ID
)

Select cte.Order_ID
, cast(cte.Trace_DateTime as date) as Trace_Date
, cast(cte.Trace_DateTime as time) as Trace_Hour,
From cte
```